# How to find breakeven amount when the buy and sell amount has a fee?

Tags: finance

With currency exchange they charge 3% when I buy a currency. When I sell they charge 3% on the amount I sell. My question: At which amount do I need to sell to make up for the 3% fees?

I currently calculating it like this (below). Currently to find the breakeven I change the $276.09 amount until I can get near to zero (when I substrate the two totals).

```
              Sell           Buy          Difference
sell/buy      $276.09   -    $260     =   $16.09
3% fee        $8.28     +    $7.8     =   $16.08

breakeven (~zero) = $16.09 - 16.08
```

I need to replace $276.09 by x. Any ideas as to what kind of formula I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to buy $B$ dollars and they charge a fraction $b$ to buy that.  You want to figure out how much $S$ to sell when there is a fraction $s$ fee.  You can deduce that

$$S = \frac{1+b}{1-s} B$$

In your example, $B=260$, $b=s=0.03$.

Comment: Wow that's incredible! Hard to wrap my head around how this works but it does!